# Singularities of a Complex Function with Complex Conjugate

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, singularity

I am trying to see what the singular points of the complex function $f(z)=\bar{z}^2-i\bar{z}$ are. Singular points is where the function fails to be continuous or is indeterminate. Just to be clear, I am getting that the function has singular points at $z=0$ and $z=-i$. I get that both are poles of order 1 of the function, as $f(z)=\bar{z}(\bar{z}-i)=\frac{|z|^2}{z}(\frac{|z|^2}{z}-i)$. Is this correct? I am starting to get myself confused.

Note: Singular points here include both zeroes and poles of $f(z)$. So my question is whether the points I found are zeroes or poles.

Definition of a pole used:

The singular point $z_0$ of an analytic function $f(z)$ is called a pole of order $n$ if $f(z)$ in the neighborhood of $z_0$ can be expressed as

$$f(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-z_0)^n} $$

where $\phi(z)$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $z_0$ and $\phi(z_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Poles are defined for  functions which are analytic except at some isolated points. This function not complex analytic anywhere so the question does not make sense unless you give us your definition of poles. .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy please see the added definition

Comment: You don't have an analytic function to begin with so your definition makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous on the whole complex plane and its zeros are at $z=0$ and $z=-i$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is conjugate analytic everywhere hence it is continuos, harmonic and  real analytic everywhere but it is not complex analytic anywhere; however, it is complex differentiable at $-\frac{i}{2}$ with derivative $0$ since $\partial_{\bar z}f=2\bar z-i$ cancels there (and for fun one can easily show that the limit at $-\frac{i}{2}$ of $\frac{f(z)-f(-\frac{i}{2})}{z+\frac{i}{2}}$ is the limit of $\frac{\bar{(z+\frac{i}{2})^2}}{z+\frac{i}{2}}$ so it is indeed zero!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, what I was asking is regarding the zeroes or poles of $f$. To clarify, I am wanting to find the singular points of $f$ (as a real vector field), so the points where it is zero (i.e. vanishes), undefined, or discontinuous. I got the points (0,0) and (0,-1). My question is, are the points poles or zeroes of the complex function $f(z)$?